# Setting up default node version on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, nvm

I have couple of node version installed thru NVM, with v14.17.1 being the latest.
Currently, every time I open a terminal I have do "nvm use v14.17.1"  otherwise "node -v" gives me following error.

```
akhil-TD0NEG8WL:~$ node -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.67.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

This is what my "nvm ls" shows

```
akhil-TD0NEG8WL:~$ nvm ls
       v12.18.3
       v14.16.0
       v14.17.1
->       system
default -> 14.17.1 (-> v14.17.1)
node -> stable (-> v14.17.1) (default)
stable -> 14.17 (-> v14.17.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> v14.17.1)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.1 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.17.1
```

I have tried "nvm alias default " which looks like it sets the default to given version. But "node -v" shows similar results even after.

```
akhil-TD0NEG8WL:~$ nvm alias default 14.17.1
default -> 14.17.1 (-> v14.17.1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: just run `nvm use default` after running your command